mice multilevel imputation: does specifying cluster variable ("-2" in predictor Matrix) without multilevel methods lead to cluster robust imputation?
In short: Are mice's imputations cluster robust when I only specify the cluster variable with "-2" in the predictor matrix but do not use multilevel models during imputation?
For clustered data, it is generally recommended to use multilevel methods both for imputation and analysis. However, it is often considered sufficient to use cluster robust standard error estimates during analysis without using multilevel models (e.g. with vcovCL in sandwich) when the observations are clustered but my research questions are unrelated to the multilevel structure. Is there an analogy for imputing in mice? What does mice do when I specify a cluster variable with "-2" in the predictor Matrix without using multilevel methods for imputation?
